Fermions to Qubits mapping in Qiskit
I am currently studying the mathematical aspects of fermion-to-qubit mapping available in Qiskit here. While I am interested in understanding the underlying transformation, I am having trouble interpreting the operators ($\hat{P}_i$) and their corresponding weights $(c_i)$. Could someone explain the role of these operators in the mapping process and how the weights are derived?
